# Is there a qualitative difference between terming things as "Name:Value" pairs and "Key:Value" pairs?

Tags: terminology

Pretty straight forward question.

QMap uses this term:

> QMap is one of Qt's generic container classes. It stores (**key, value**) pairs and provides fast lookup of the value associated with a key.
>   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html

xattr in its documentation uses the term:

> Extended attributes are **name:value** pairs associated permanently with       files and directories, similar to the environment strings associated       with a process.  An attribute may be defined or undefined.  If it is       defined, its value may be empty or non-empty. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html

Is there a qualitative difference between "keys" and "names"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A name is a kind or an implementation of the key concept — the term key is more generic than string, a key can be a string, an integer, a symbol, or other type that supports hashing and equality comparison.

Usually, a key will be supported by (generic) type parameter; whereas a name is taken as a string.